# Can you please create a tag for Counterpart?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I have a question about my Movies & TV Stack Exchange post: [Whats the weapon Nadia Fierro/Baldwin uses in Counterpart S01E08 to kill the guy in his flat?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/92582/whats-the-weapon-nadia-fierro-baldwin-uses-in-counterpart-s01e08-to-kill-the-guy)

Can you please add a tag for counterpart, I had to tag my question with a tag for a related movie, because i needed at least one tag.

Comment: People'd've done it sooner or later. Anyway, it's there now.